# Connecting to an IP Camera

Tags: router, ip, routing

I have long experience with networks but I lost the track to it.

So I have an IP Camera linked to my router. I can access it through my local network using it IP Address (192.168.2.xx). Now I want to access it through another distant computer (through the Internet).

I remember (3 years ago), I did something similar to access a computer remote desktop application. It has an IP and I forwarded this IP (using a port I think) and then by some means I linked it to DynDNS, so that I can type a real domain like mycomp.dyndns.com and access my computer (or if dyndns down I can still use my internet IP with the port)

Now I want to do the same thing, but really don't find the track, there are some settings I'm missing, please can someone detail to me the steps, I hope you understood what I want to do; my camera is Dlink DCS 920, my router is Sagem (if that can help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know about networks, it easy, dont worry ;)

Step by step:

1º Make an account in a Dynamic DNS service like [No-Ip](http://www.no-ip.com/) or [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/), and install the client in your computer or configure your router to synchronize your Dynamic IP with a DNS name.

2º Fix the IP of your camera in your internal Network in the configuration of your router (it may be in DHCP config or something like that).

3º Go to NAT Settings (also called Virtual Servers) in configuration of your router and Open the port of the camera (usually 80 for cameras) from the router to the internal IP of the camera.

4º Access to the camera from you want ;-)

See you!

Comment: +1 for the 'no worries' confidence booster...and the good advice

Answer (score 1):

You just need to be careful what you expose to the internet. Firstly unless the camera requires some sort of authentication, anyone will be able to access it and control it remotely (may be undesirable depending on what the camera is looking at).

Secondly, you will want to make sure that the firmware on the camera is up to date and contains no known vulnerabilities.  Remember, this is essentially a fully fledged network device.  If there is an exploitable vulnerability in the device, then potentially someone could compromise the camera, and then use it to launch further attacks either into your network or back out into the internet.

If you do truly want this device internet accessible I would look at the option of creating a DMZ off your router and isolating the camera in there.

This may sound paranoid but believe me, it does happen.

Comment: +1, because security is really important in this situations.